# Eclipse doesn't autocomplete and find references anymore

Tags: eclipse

A few days ago I was using autocomplete features and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click without any problem.

But now those features don't work anymore: the autocomplete shows up but is always empty, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click doesn't work because Eclipse doesn't recognize the classes anymore.

This doesn't even work for a class or function or variable in the same file, so I guess this is not a configuration problem, but maybe a cache that is corrupted?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to *Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Advanced*.
- Make sure *Other Java Proposals* is ticked/checked

If that does not work simply "close" the project and reopen it.

Comment: That did the trick thank you ! I am using Eclipse for PHP, so I tried closing and reopening the project and it worked. Exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: Kepler didn't have this turned on by default when I downloaded it for some reason

Comment: +1 same thing. Kepler didn't have this turned on by default. Hopefully other people will come by and see this fix. (

Eclipse Kepler Turn On Content Assist AutoComplete Intellisense)

Comment: I dunno why Kepler doesn't have this on by default. That's a must for android dev.

Comment: close/reopen worked for me.

Comment: reopening the project worked...you are a genius!

Comment: Luna Release (4.4.0) - Modifying the preferences didn't appear to do anything for me. Closing/reopening didn't work either. I ended up deleting/re-adding the project and that worked.

Comment: Same solution worked for System Workbench stm32.

Comment: This steps resolved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This was a tough one for me to solve (running Juno Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800 on Mac OSX 10.6.8).

The steps I had to take were:

1. Run *Help » Check for updates* and then restart to get to the most recent version
2. As noted above, Go to *Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Advanced*
3. Click everything Java related in both sections
4. Restart again

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu studio the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> was assigned at the operating system level to change the keyboard input method. I had to change the *Next Input Method* in *Settings Manager–>Keyboard Input Methods–>Next Input Method* field.

I changed it from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know who designed this but the choice of ctrl+space to change the keyboard input method is really dumb.

Comment: this is solution is also applicable for Mac Os. go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources and untick that stupid control-space binding.